# Error received on join update, incorrect syntax

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update

I'm receiving an error on the below SQL in MySQL and i'm unsure why. I'm new to MySQL.

```
UPDATE I
SET I.user_comments = DD.value
FROM
redcap_user_information I
    JOIN redcap_data D ON D.value = I.user_email AND D.project_id = 439 AND D.field_name = 'email'
    JOIN redcap_data DD ON DD.record = D.record AND DD.project_id = 439 AND DD.field_name = 'irb'
WHERE
user_comments IS NULL
    AND allow_create_db = 1
    AND user_suspended_time IS NULL
ORDER BY I.user_email
```

The error is

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM
 redcap_user_information I
     JOIN redcap_data D ON D.value = I.use'
```

Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the logic of the join part but the correct syntax for update with join would be as

```
update redcap_user_information I
JOIN redcap_data D ON D.value = I.user_email AND D.project_id = 439 AND D.field_name = 'email'
JOIN redcap_data DD ON DD.record = D.record AND DD.project_id = 439 AND DD.field_name = 'irb'
set I.user_comments = DD.value
WHERE
user_comments IS NULL --- use the table alias name to access the column 
AND allow_create_db = 1 --- use the table alias name to access the column
AND user_suspended_time IS NULL --- use the table alias name to access the column
```

Comment: Oh, that's different to MS SQL's - UPDATE, SET, FROM, JOIN, WHERE. Thank you anyway, that worked.